# PDF Alternative to DOCX

Tags: pdf, windows-services, automation, docx

We have an application that uses Word Documents in an auto-printing process. Customer shows up, gets registered and - depending on location & services requested - different documents print where appropriate (wrist band and reciepts in the printer closests to the customer, and Order forms upstairs, for example).

To make this happen, we have a 2 stage process:

Stage 1 (Document Preparation, Word & VBA Scripts):

1. Create word document
2. Add Custom Document Properties to Word Document. CustLastName, CustFirstName, CustAddress1, CustZip, etc
3. Place Fields on document that point to the Custom Properties.

Stage 2 (Document Usage, C# Application):

1. Load Document
2. Load customer information from database
3. Update Custom Document Properties with correct information from database:
   CustLastName = Doe, CustFirstName = John, etc
4. Update Fields (refreshes document, replacing visible information with correct customer information)
5. Print to desired printer (size, orientation, 1/2 sided, etc)
6. Log, Rinse, lather, repeat.

**The main problem with Word**  is printing inside of a windows service. Currently our process requires an Office installation and a logged in user. Word does not play well without a user shell and operation inside a windows service isn't supported.

I'd like to remove word and move our process to a background Windows Service. I'm unsure of how to do a similar process with PDF (or similar document formats): Update fields and Print.

If I was to create a PDF (Even if it's a Word "Save As... PDF") with the intent of being able use Document Properties to drive Update-able fields on the form and then finally print the document in a windows service, where is a good place to start looking?

Comment: You could do your process up to stage 2 step 5 in docx format, but without using Word (see eg Open XML SDK).  Then its just a matter of printing the docx; at this point you could convert to PDF or HTML etc to print.

Comment: I agree with @JasonPlutext here. give [OpenXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) a try. Without any xml like experience it took me a day to get my first decent excel document with some formatting, but it's worth it. It's free and gives you maximum flexibility.